# How to override PhoneAccentBrush on High Contrast WP8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, high-contrast

I have a problem in my app. On all screens I have hard-coded "White" Background and for text color (Foreground) I use PhoneAccentBrush. Everything was fine before I check high-contrast option in ease of access. Then PhoneAccentBrush turns white, and I end up with white text on white background. I check how can I solve the problem and it seems to me that the best option is overriding PhoneAccentBrush in high-contrast mode (I also thought about converter, but I have to much text to use it everywhere). Basically all I want to do is set PhoneAccentBrush black in high-contrast. I fight with this for hours now and still have nothing. I check this:
[How to ignore "ease of access" settings on Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995376/how-to-ignore-ease-of-access-settings-on-windows-phone)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208807?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and ("High contrast sample" on the bottom of page)
and still have nothing.
When I try to use MSDN example it doesn't work on WP (it's preparend for full Windows) - when I paste this code into app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Sample-Utils/SampleTemplateStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I get errors:
"Each dictionary entry must have an associated key."
"Dictionary Item 'ResourceDictionary' must have a Key attribute" so it's different on Windows Phone. With method from stack overflow link I get the same, I try to give "Default" or "HighContrast" key for Dictionary, but I doesn't work. Also I found list of all keys on MSDN but PhoneAccentBrush isn't there. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a themed resource dictionary, in your app.xaml file, where you set your foreground brush for different themes:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- Non-themed resources -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush" Color="DarkBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush" Color="Gray" />

        <!-- Themed resources -->
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyForegroundBrush" Color="{Binding Source={ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}, Path=Color}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyForegroundBrush" Color="{Binding Source={ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}, Path=Color}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrastBlack">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyForegroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrastWhite">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyForegroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrastCustom">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyForegroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Notice how MyForegroundBrush uses the PhoneAccentBrush in the dark/light themes, but is hardcoded to an appropiate colour in the high contrast modes.

In your XAML just use MyForegroundBrush as normal, and the correct version will be used depending on the current theme.

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource MyForegroundBrush}">
```

Just a thought, though, if a user has set their theme to high contrast black they generally want a black background. Is hard coding it to white in your app the right thing to do? You could use the above approach to create a background brush that is white in the Light/High Contrast White themes, but black in the High Contrast Black theme.

Comment: Your explenation is very good - now I have better approach to the problem, but still when I paste above code to App.xaml I've got "Dictionary Item 'ResourceDictionary' must have a Key attribute". What Key should I use? I try to use "Default" and it compiled, but when I go to the page with Foreground="{ThemeResource MyForegroundBrush}" I get error "WinRT information: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key MyForegroundBrush [Line: 254 Position: 40]"

Comment: I’ve just created a blank WP8.1 project and tried the above code, just in case I made a mistake, but it worked as expected. So, I’m not sure why you’re getting an error – each ResourceDictionary has a key and the keys are valid. Could there something else in your app.xaml that is causing the problem?

Comment: Indeed in blank project it works fine ;/ Here's all code from App.xaml wich give me this Key error http://pastebin.com/0eA5RTGU  and when I try move ThemeDictionary above like this: http://pastebin.com/GzEeFYCT I've got error: "This Member 'Resources' has more than one item, use the Items property" So I think we're getting close, but sadly I don't see any <Items> or <Application.Items> or <Application.Resources.Items>

Comment: I can see why it's not working - the problem you've got now is that you've defined some resources outside of the ResourceDictionary. Just move all of those resources (brushes, converters, and data template) inside the ResourceDictionary and everything should be OK. I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced the missing PhoneAccentBrush in the resource dictionary. It turned out I removed the default page background which points to the resource dictionary, and when I placed it back it worked: Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"